# Editar registros de um clientdataset de campos advindo de um join

Tags: mysql, delphi, join

Tenho um exemplo simples, porém em três camadas, com sqldataset + datasetprovider + clientdataset. Não carrego nenhum field no sqldataset. No datasetprovider deixo o updatemode em upwherekeyonly.

No datasetprovider eu deixo allowcommandtext como true para poder receber commandtext do lado cliente via clientdataset. No lado cliente eu carrego os fields com Select * ... e durante o tempo de execução envio o commandtext com um join de forma que traga so os campos já carregados. Quando tento editar algum registro e dar o applyupdates no evento onreconcileerror recebo:

```
Unable to Find Record. No Key especified
```

Uso xe5+dbexpress+mysql. A pergunta é como devo configurar os componentes para editar e atualizar registros vindo de um command com join?

**RESUMINDO A DISCUSSÃO**

Pode-se deixar todas as configurações padrão do delphi, a unica coisa que é preciso é colocar no evento OnGetTablename do datasetprovider o nome da tabela a ser atualizada, isso resolveu todos os meus problemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artur, isto acontece porque para o DataSet entende que todos os campos pertencem a mesma tabela.

Para corrigir o problema, você deve configurar quais campos não são campos de dados da tabela, qual a chave e qual a tabela a ser atualizada.

#### Configurar corretamente os campos

Uma forma de se fazer isso é setando a propriedade [**ProviderFlags**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Data.DB.TProviderFlag) para vazio, dizendo que o campo não deve aparecer nem no *Where* e nem ser atualizado (*pfInWhere, pfInUpdate*).

```
CampoA.ProviderFlags := [];
```

Ou alterando o [**FieldKind**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Data.DB.TField.FieldKind) para **fkInternalCalc**.

```
CampoA.FieldKind := fkInternalCalc;
```

Outra coisa importante é definir o campo chave primária, para garantir que o provider identifique corretamente a chave a ser utilizada, e para isso você deve setar o **ProviderFlag** para ***pfInKey***

```
CampoChave.ProviderFlags := CampoChave.ProviderFlags + [pfInKey];
```

ou
    CampoChave.ProviderFlags := [pfInUpdate, pfInKey];

#### Definir o nome da tabela a ser atualizada

Além disso, é recomendado implementar o evento ***onGetTableName*** do ***TDataSetProvider***, para que ele saiba em qual tabela dar update.

```
procedure DataSetProvider.onGetTableName(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Result := 'NomeDaTabelaASerAtualizada';
end;
```

Comment: @Capauto obrigado pela resposta quando chegar no pc te retorno. Só lembrando, como disse acima, no meu inner join não trago campos de outra tabela, apenas de uma, eu faço tipo duas filtragens em uma tabela, mestre/detalhe.

Comment: Nesse caso ignore a parte de tirar campos do update e where, mude apenas o campo key e defina o nome da tabela. Faz um bom tempo que não mexo com datasets mas se bem me lembro fazíamos assim.  Qualquer coisa só notifica aqui que posso ajudar mais se não resolver.

Comment: deu certo, realmente o problema era não ter o evento ongettable o nome da tabela, muito obrigado!

Comment: agora o problema é que não edita nem deleta, mas salva, aparece: Unable to find record. No key specified.

Comment: Consegui resolver, coloquei em vez de upwherekeyonly, upwhereall. Muito obrigado mais uma vez.